# How can I access random point without full reading?

Tags: python, file-io

I have a huge data set to train word2vec.
example is as follows.

```
15 24 0
22 23 1 
11 15 0 
22 27 1 
...
```

I want to randomly sample it.

I tried with codecs function and split function.

But that file is too big, so that code make memory error.

To avoid memory error, I use for and open(). for example,

```
for line in open(fileNM):
    train(line)
```

But in this way, I can access data only in a sequential way.

How can I randomly access data with out full reading?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the python built-in `linecache` library for getting a line from file:

https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/linecache.html

Answer (score 0):

if you know how many lines the file has you can use something like:

```
import pandas
import random

row_count = 10000000
sample_size = 10000
file_name = "xyz.csv"
skip_set = set(np.random.choice(row_count, row_count-sample_size))
df = pandas.read_csv(file_name, sep=' ', skiprows=lambda x: x in skip_set)
```